# error: 'template<class T> class Dynamic_Array' used without template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I've been getting this error for some time, and I have no clue how to fix it.
I searched for similar problem here on stack overflow, but I've failed to find anything.

Source code:

```
template <typename T>
class Dynamic_Array
{
private:
    T* actual_array;
    unsigned int number_of_elements;
public:
    Dynamic_Array() {}
    ~Dynamic_Array() {delete[] actual_array;}

    unsigned int get_size() const {return number_of_elements;}

    T& operator [](unsigned int index) {return actual_array[index];}
    void operator +=(T&);
    void operator -=(unsigned int);

};

template <typename T> /*Not sure if this is needed, but compiler doesn't mind, still prints the same error*/

void Dynamic_Array<T>::operator+=(T& object)
{
    if(number_of_elements>1)
    {
        T* temp_array = new T[number_of_elements];
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<number_of_elements;i++)
        {
            temp_array[i]=actual_array[i];
        }
        delete[] actual_array;

        actual_array = new T[number_of_elements+1];
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<number_of_elements;i++)
        {
            actual_array[i]=temp_array[i];
        }
        delete [] temp_array;
        temp_array=NULL;

        actual_array[number_of_elements]=object;

        number_of_elements++;
    }
    else
    {
        number_of_elements++;
        actual_array = new T[1];
    }
}
void Dynamic_Array<T>::operator-=(unsigned int index)
{
    T* temp_array = new T[number_of_elements-1];
    for(unsigned int i=0, j=0;i<number_of_elements;i++)
    {
        if(i!=index)
        {
            temp_array[j]=actual_array[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    delete[] actual_array;
    number_of_elements--;

    actual_array = new T[number_of_elements];
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<number_of_elements;i++)
    {
        actual_array[i]=temp_array[i];
    }
    delete [] temp_array;
    temp_array = NULL;
}
```

According to compiler, the error is present in line 18 (the empty one between "};" and "template"

As I said, I have no idea what I screwed up, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: For your next error: [Rule of Three/Five/Zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: Nope, it's just after the class declaration.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, after restarting IDE a few times it works! Thanks everyone for quick replies.

Comment: @XONX - re: "it's just after the class declaration" -- there is no class declaration. There is a template definition. Don't muddle the two or you'll find yourself deeply confused.

Answer (score 1):

When you define member functions outside of a class template declaration then you need to specify the template for each function.  When you define

```
void Dynamic_Array<T>::operator-=(unsigned int index)
{
    //...
}
```

You need to have the template part as well like

```
template <typename T>
void Dynamic_Array<T>::operator-=(unsigned int index)
{
    //...
}
```

This has to be present for every function definition that you do out of line.  A single `template <typename T>` at the start of all the definition does not apply to all of the function definitions.

Comment: Well, there is one before the += operator definition. EDIT: Also, when I added another before the -= operator definition, I still get the same error.

Comment: @XONX You have to do it for every function you define outside of the class body.

Answer (score 0):

`Dynamic_Array` is a template class so when defining `operator+=` and `operator-=` outside the scope of the class you need to provide template type as follows:

```
template<typename T> void Dynamic_Array<T>::operator+=(T& object) {
    //...
}

template<typename T> void Dynamic_Array<T>::operator-=(unsigned int index) {
    //...
}
```

Also, I should note that it is somewhat odd to have `void` as a return type for `operator+=` and `operator-=`, typically you should return a reference to the altered instance of `this`, i.e:

```
template<typename T> Dynamic_Array<T>& Dynamic_Array<T>::operator+=(const T& object) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Yea, I do realise I probably made tons of mistakes in making a dynamic array class, but I'm more concerned about the template problem right now, which still applies even after providing templates for every member function. Thanks for the advice tho.